# Unity C# Reflection. Custom Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

As a workout, I wanted to try writing my own Dependency Injection for Unity. And faced the problem of Nullreferenceexception when injecting into fields. There is a `Player` class that spawns `Enemy` and, using reflection, sets the value in the `_player` field obtained from `Container`. But for some reason the `_player` field remains null. I decided to add Debug to all methods to track the field. And it is output to the console:

```
Init Enemy player (Player)
Start Enemy

Null
NullReferenceException
Null
NullReferenceException...
```

It can be seen that in the `InitEnemy` method the field got its value, but already in the `Start` method the field became null. And in `Update` too. Where can there be a mistake?

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [InjectField] private Player _player;

    public void InitEnemy()
    {
        Debug.Log("Init Enemy " + _player);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Start Enemy " + _player);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(_player);
        _player.TakeDamage(10);
    }
}
```

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    [SerializeField]
    private Enemy _enemyPrefab;
  
    private void Awake()
    {   
        Container.BindSingleton(this);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damg)
    {
        Debug.Log("player dmg! " + damg);
    }

    [Button]
    public void Spawn()
    {
        Enemy spawnedEnemy = InstantiateAndBind(_enemyPrefab);   
        spawnedEnemy.InitEnemy();     
    }

    public T InstantiateAndBind<T>(T prefab) where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        T scriptToInject = Instantiate(prefab);
        Type scriptType = prefab.GetType();

        var fieldsToInject = new List<FieldInfo>();

        FieldInfo[] fields = scriptType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            if (Attribute.IsDefined(field, typeof(InjectField)))
            {
                fieldsToInject.Add(field);
            }
        }

        foreach (FieldInfo bindField in fieldsToInject)
        {        
            bindField.SetValue(scriptToInject, Container.Get(bindField.FieldType));
        }

        return T;
    }
}
```

```
public static class Container
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _bindClasses = new(128);

    public static void BindSingleton<T>(T instance) where T : class
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        if (_bindClasses.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        _bindClasses.Add(typeof(T), instance);
    }

    public static T Get<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (_bindClasses.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return (T)_bindClasses[typeof(T)];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public static object Get(Type type) 
    {
        if (_bindClasses.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return _bindClasses[type];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Can Garbage Collector remove links if you set values in fields through reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect a typo there or an issue in a part of code you didn't share.

Your provided code wouldn't compile at

```
public T InstantiateAndBind<T>(T prefab) where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    return T;
}
```

I copied all your exact code except for replacing that by

```
    return scriptToInject;
```

(and `[Button]` by `[ContextMenu(nameof(Spawn))]` since I don't have you external library ;) )

=> I can't reproduce your issue:

[image]